# Android apk for (nearly) professional video edit

Tags: video-editor, android

Is there any better aplication for nearly professional video edit than PowerDirector Video Editor ? 
I've tried many, also Premiere which I'm also using on my desktop, but nothing was that profesional that above mentioned app. I need quality output rather than fancy effects.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it the Adobe Premiere Clip apk you said you used, or is it Premiere on desktop?

For professional video edits it is recommended you use the desktop as most of the Video Editing apps come with tons of effects,fancy items for quick, easy use. I personally would recommend to try out [Quik Video Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stupeflix.replay&hl=en) over below mentioned Video Editors,when it comes to Android.

Quik Video Editor features:

- Free
- Photos and Videos limit - 75
- Carefully designed Video transitions and graphics
- Beat sync transitions
- Output quality ( 1080p/720p)
- Video styles (Raw/stylish )

  **The other Apps that you can use (Not recommended - but you can try)**
- FilmoraGo Video Editor
- Viva Video editor
- Kine Master
- **Magisto Video Editor & Maker (Second suggestion)**
- Adobe Premiere Clip

All of the aforementioned apps offer basic video-editing features. Some excel at social media integration, some are clearly designed to be a desktop replacement. Which one works best for you will depend on your needs which is "Professional video edit and quality output".

The best thing is that all of the apps mentioned are either completely free or offer a free version. Give them a try and see which is the best fit for you.

For a fact: *"Since some apps are clearly designed to be a desktop replacement,we cannot expect desktop quality professional edits,outputs (codecs,fps) from the apps which come for the mobile devices"*

Comment: Thank you for complex reply. Well, I just need to put together videos, so I was currious about quality over any fancy video effects for social networks. 
My main target is youtube and as I'm constantly travelling, I appriciate to have apk despite I know that on PC it's simply better. On PC I use Adobe Premiere Pro which is fantastic...
/// I've found another interesting apk called KineMaster, will also try it out

Comment: It is recommended to use Magisto Video editor if you are going for social networks such as Facebook.If its youtube you can try out Quik video,and FilmoraGo. KineMaster also has good features ,effects and transitions.Cheers and Good luck on you carrier!